# Python: How to import a module from a parent directory

Tags: python, import, path, directory-structure, project-structure

I know there are many similar questions out there already, but none of the answers did really work for me, so please read my question first (and tell me where I went wrong with the other solutions) before marking this as duplicate.

My project structure looks like this:

```
Project/
|-- src/
    |-- project/
        |-- a.py
        |-- b.py
        |-- tests/
            |--c.py
```

I don't know much about how to strucure python projects/how packages etc. work exactly.
I want to import `a` in my `c` module.

I tried things like

```py
from project.a import xyz
```

```py
from ..a import xyz
```

I also added `__init__.py` files to both the `project` and the `tests` directory.

But still I always get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

Then I tried adding the `project` path to my `sys.path` before importing `a`, but still I get the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `__init__.py`, and adding the project path with `sys.path`, and import `a` should work. But I would recommend to try the following in your `c.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path(__file__)
filepath = filepath.parent
sys.path.insert(0, str(filepath))
import a
```

Why? This is a generic solution that will work as long as the relative path from `c` to `a` stays the same.

Comment: I added `__init__.py` files in both dirs, but still it's not working. I get the same error.

Comment: What exactly is the import statement? Does just "import a" work?

Comment: It didn't, but when I replaced `sys.path.insert` with `sys.path.append` somehow it worked, however I'm pretty sure that I already tried exactly that before... Maybe I did something else wrong that time, I don't know